# Setting inverse kinematics relative to local coordinates of an object

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I’m just studying rigging, and I have a non-trivial problem that I can’t solve on my own. I’m trying to create an IK with a limiter for the mechanical limb. When I rotate the object relative to the 3D cursor, which is at the support point of this object, everything is fine, but I cannot adjust the IK bone with the limiter so that the rotation coordinates at the bone coincide with the coordinates of the support point. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

The first video shows the right movement, but it’s around the axis, not the bones.
[image]

And in this video, what happens when you try to set the bone of the inverse kinematics to rotate.[image]

Link to blender file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PyipmlnD2gXE6hDlmtDJq0esksRQx1mu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: how should we be able to help you without seeing any of your settings? Rigging is a quite complex thing and we have no idea what you did. So pls provide blend file, so we can check it out. thx.

Comment: there is no IK at all in your provided blend file. so pls add your "try" in your blend file although it doesn't work so we can help you.

Comment: An IK chain is meant to control a chain of at least two bones from two points A to B by moving only A or B. Like moving a hand to move the arm and forearm. What you show in your GIFs doesn't look like an IK scenario, so are you sure you need an IkK setup here? What are you trying to achieve?